# How to Deploy a web API built in .NET Core 2.1 into Weblogic?

Tags: .net, iis, weblogic, asp.net-core-webapi, weblogic12c

The organization I work in doesn't want to use IIS for hosting my new Web API. I have two options now one option is to deploy my .Net Core Application into Weblogic or I would have to re write my code into a Windows Application.

Comment: WebLogic is a Java application server, not a .NET application server and then it will not be able to handle your application.

Comment: "The organization I work in doesn't want to use IIS." They cannot only use WebLogic. Ask them if they use Apache or nginx as reverse proxy in front of WebLogic. If either is used, you can put Kestrel/ASP.NET Core behind the same reverse proxy. .NET Core does not rely on WebLogic.